# Alter Assembly not altering an assembly

Tags: sql, sql-server, clr, sqlclr, clrstoredprocedure

Recently we have noticed that `ALTER ASSEMBLY` is not updating the dll on the SQL Server. We have been altering the assembly since last two years and never had an issue before. The major change we have done is upgraded the targetted framework on the assembly to 4.8. I don't think this is an issue because we were able to alter another assembly on which we have upgraded the framework to 4.8. We have even decompiled the assembly and validated that our latest code is part of it. When we tracked the ModifiedDate in sys.assemblies, realized that the dll has not been updated. It is still pointing to the old date, while the other dlls got a latest modified date.

No errors or warnings are logged on the SSMS and SQL Server event viewer while running the Alter Assembly. We are not sure why is the assembly not updating. Please help us in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What method are you using to deploy the assembly? If you're able to run your `alter assembly... ` and the check against sys.assemblies in the same query, that'd eliminate any possibility of the deployment target and the where you're checking against being different in any way. Also, ideally, you're using the assembly_bits version of `alter assembly` (i.e. providing a varbinary representation) to eliminate another potential source of deploying something other than what you intended.

Comment: We are using SQL SERVER ALTER ASSEMBLY command to modify the assembly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-assembly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Of course - you have to. What I'm suggesting is using `ALTER ASSEMBLY AssemblyName 
FROM 0xabcd1234` rather than `ALTER ASSEMBLY AssemblyName 
FROM '\\path\to\file.dll'`.